# Multiple Settings.bundle in an iOS app

Tags: ios, settings, bundle, target

I have an iOS app project with two targets.

I currently have a single Settings.bundle for both targets, but I would like to be able to make one for each.

Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is.

Create a group in the `Project Navigator` and name it something useful (perhaps after your first target) and drag your existing `Settings.bundle` inside it. Set the `Target Membership` of this `Settings.bundle` to only be the the first target.

Now create a second group and call it something useful (perhaps after the name of your second target) and create a new `Settings.bundle` inside it and set the `Target Membership` of this `Settings.bundle` to the second target.